# unable to load a file and show in browser which has date and time in the filename

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

My requirement is to create a file and load on browser using java. The below code works perfectly but its failing to load the file in browser when i 
create a filename with date and time.
ex) `MyDataAccessList20170719103457.pdf` or `MyDataAccessList07-19-2017_10-50AM.pdf` - fails to load
   `MyDataAccessList.pdf` - loads the file successfully in browser

html:

```
<div ng-controller="myFileReadCtrl">
<object-reloadable> </object-reloadable>
</div>
```

js code:

```
myApp.controller('myFileReadCtrl', function ($scope, FilesService) {
      $scope.fileRead = function () {
        FilesService.fileRead().then(
            function (response) {
                 $scope.filePathAndName = response;
                   if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                    $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.pdfName = response;
                        var html = '<object type="application/pdf" data="' + newValue + '"></object>';
                         var replacementElement = angular.element(html);
                         currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                         currentElement = replacementElement;*/
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                    $scope.filePathAndName = response;
                 }
            },
          function (errResponse) {
                $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
            });

    }
   $scope.fileRead();
});
```

spring controller : code written in spring controller to create a file

```
//the js code hits this controller where i'm generating a pdf with content and returning the file and pathname so that it loads the pdf file in the browser.
//code to create a filename with date and time
        String FILE_PATH = "C:\\myFiles\\";
        String FILE_EXTENSION = "pdf";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss"); 
          try {
                    file_name = "MyDataAccessList" +  "." + FILE_EXTENSION; //working, loads the created file on the browser
                    file_name = "MyDataAccessList" + df.format(new Date()) + "." + FILE_EXTENSION; //not working, doesn't load the file
                    filename = FILE_PATH + file_name;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
          File file = new File(filename);
          //logic to write data into file
          return filename;
```

The above code works perfectly when i don't include the date and time in the filename when i create a pdf file.What is the reason that it is failing to load the file which has date and time in the filename.

The error in the browser console when i included date and time in the filename is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: If you are getting 404 means your server side has some issue. Check the logs on the server side.

Comment: It is unable to load the file which has date and time.With the same code if filename is MyDataAccessList20170719103457.pdf it is showing the 404 error. when i remove df.format(new Date())  while creating file_name it is loading the file in browser( MyDataAccessList.pdf)